# how to close form through another form in windows form c++?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, visual-c++-2017

I want to close a form through clicking a button in another form.

The form I want to close is `BreakEndOptions.h` and the button to be clicked is in form `Confirmation.h`

I already included `BreakEndOptions.h` in the header of `Confirmation.h`. How do you access it and perform *Close()*? Or are there other ways?

Currently I tried `BreakEndOptions::Close();` but there is an error saying **a nonstatic member reference must be relative to a specific object.**

I also tried

```
BreakEndOptions^ break = gcnew BreakEndOptions;
break->Close();
```

but it still has errors. What is the correct way?

Comment: I don't think you can use `break` as identifier

Comment: This invariably gets C++ programmers into trouble.  You have a circular dependency between the .h files.  BreakEndOptions.h needs to #include Confirmation.h so it can display that form, no problems.  But Confirmation.h cannot #include BreakEndOptions.h.  There are multiple solutions, but in this specific case it is pretty unlikely that the Confirmation form object needs to stay on the screen after BreakEndOptions closes.  That is easy to do, use ShowDialog() instead.  When it returns DialogResult::OK then call this->Close().

Comment: Other ways: pass an object reference though the Confirmation class constructor, of type Form^, pass `this`.  Or raise an event in Configuration that BreakEndOptions subscribes.